# How to find the value of an attribute

Tags: sql, winforms, entity-framework-mapping

How can I find the value of an attribute? I need to check the value and set the textbox maxlength to that value. Here is an example of the value I'm looking to retrieve.

```
public class DogClass
    {
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string LegalName
        {
        }
```

Comment: you mean like return _LegalName ?

Comment: I need to return 5 some how. So I can set the textbox maxlength to 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to get this info. Below is a snippet that should get you started.

```
protected void GetStringLength(object objDog) {
    // loop through each property in object
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in objDog.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        // for each object property, get the SringLength tag (if there is one)
        foreach (Attribute attribute in Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(pi, typeof(StringLengthAttribute), true))
           {
                // we'll assume there is only one 
                var stringLenVal = (attribute as StringLengthAttribute).MaximumLength;
                break;
           }
    }
}
```